# Run batch file using visual studio command prompt from power-shell script

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, command-prompt

I want to run a batch file using using visual studio command prompt in power-shell script. Right now the build.bat file is run using the command prompt like this "cmd /c "build.bat" in my power-shell script.

I want to use visual studio command prompt to run it instead of regular command prompt in the power-shell script. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by _visual studio command prompt_?

Comment: Are you talking about the [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) ?